# Absolute path and testing with IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I wrote most of my url by starting at the root (notice the slash at the beginning).

```
<img src="/Content/Images/example.png" />
```

Everything works fine when I debug in VS and when it's published in production.

Now I decided to test/debug the website with my mobile devices on my LAN. To do this I had to "Use Local IIS Web server" since port 46918 is blocked for some reason. This forces me to specify a virtual directory therefore my path don't work any more.

Since I don't want to use relative path, is there a proper way to write urls in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use relative URLs and let ASP.NET attach the prefix for you:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/example.png")" />
```

In development, that will resolve to just `/Content...` while in your virtual directory environment you'll get `/virtualdirectory/Content...`.

Answer (score 2):

Using MVC, use `@Url.Content(...)`.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/example.png")" />
```

The `Url.Content()` method will figure out where your application lies under the IIS root and adjust the links accordingly:

```
/Content/Images/example.png
```

or

```
/SomeVirtualPath/Content/Images/example.png
```

You can use this for any URl you need (css files, javascript files, images, etc.)